# How return all objects that contain same value but in different fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have some objects in array. How to return the objects that contain value "FP5Ap", it may be in fields "t1n" or "t2n".
Many thanks.

```
{
    "matches" : [
            {
                    "t1n" : "0oDQw",
                    "t2n" : "0IjzE",
                    "t1g" : 2,
                    "t2g" : 1,
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "t1n" : "0oDQw",
                    "t2n" : "TONuT",
                    "t1g" : 2,
                    "t2g" : 0,
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "t1n" : "0oDQw",
                    "t2n" : "FP5Ap",
                    "t1g" : 4,
                    "t2g" : 0,
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "t1n" : "FP5Ap",
                    "t2n" : "TONuT",
                    "t1g" : 4,
                    "t2g" : 0,
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ]
```

}

Comment: use $or for example db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { t1n: FP5Ap }, { t2n: FP5ap } ] } )

Comment: The $or operator return empty response too.

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

```
db.countries.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$matches"},
    {"$project":{"_id":0, "matches":1}},
    {"$match": {"$or": [{"matches.t1n":"FP5Ap"},{"matches.t2n":"FP5Ap"}]}}
]).pretty()
```

and got answer

```
{
    "matches" : {
        "t1n" : "0oDQw",
        "t2n" : "FP5Ap",
        "t1g" : 4,
        "t2g" : 0,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
    }
}
{
    "matches" : {
        "t1n" : "FP5Ap",
        "t2n" : "TONuT",
        "t1g" : 4,
        "t2g" : 0,
        "date" : ISODate("2020-10-10T00:00:00Z")
    }
}
```